# How to shade the region on the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble understanding the following set:

> $$\{ \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1| = |z-i|\}.$$

How would I shade the region of it?

Comment: Hint : $|z-1|$ is the distance between the point of affix z and the point of affix 1. $|z-i|$ is the distance between the point of affix z and the point of affix $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $|z-w|$ is the distance between numbers $z$ and $w$ in the complex plane.

So $z$ is equaly from $1$ and $i$, and thus $z$ is on a perpendicular bisector of the segment between $1$ and $i$.

Comment: So z can be any point on this straight line? I think now I understand :P Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you find answer usefull then please do upvote and accept the answer which is most usefull to you!

Answer (score 1):

In words, $z$ has to be equidistant from $1$ and $i$. All you have to do is draw the straight line.